# Google Play Games apk detailed list button bar css?

Tags: css, tags, apk, google-play-games, group

The detailed list section at the bottom of the google play games apk application caught my attention. When I wanted to do the same, I searched on the internet but couldn't find it. Can I learn css codes from application? or is there a codepen example on the internet that has the same functionality?

Below are screenshots
[image: image imgur link here]

Can I learn css codes from application? or is there a codepen example on the internet that has the same functionality?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most apps from Google are not HTML based and thus don't use CSS. These apps make use of the Android UI framework which is only available within Android apps. Some apps may include webviews so partially content may be based on HTML&CSS but just by looking at the screen shots it is next to impossible to see which parts of the screen are native Android UI and which Webviews. So I don't think you can learn CSS from those apps.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I appreciate your comment. I only know css and to search for a similar structure with css, what should I search for on the internet. I guess I should search for something like "Tags group button bar" or maybe "radio selected horizantally nested radio group shows". I'll do some more research on the internet, maybe I'll find something. thanks for your comment